# How to call Lua table value explicitly when using integer counter (i,j,k) in a for loop to make the table name/address?

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

I have to be honest that I don't quite understand Lua that well yet. I am trying to overwrite a local numeric value assigned to a set table address (is this the right term?).

The addresses are of the type:

`project.models.stor1.inputs.T_in.default`, `project.models.stor2.inputs.T_in.default` and so on with the `stor` number increasing.

I would like to do this in a for loop but cannot find the right expression to make the entire string be accepted by Lua as a table address (again, I hope this is the right term).

So far, I tried the following to concatenate the strings but without success in calling and then overwriting the value:

```
for k = 1,10,1 do
project.models.["stor"..k].inputs.T_in.default = 25
end
```

```
for k = 1,10,1 do
"project.models.stor"..j..".T_in.default" = 25
end
```

**EDIT:**

I think I found the solution as per https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html:

> A common mistake for beginners is to confuse a.x with a[x]. The first form represents a["x"], that is, a table indexed by the string "x". The second form is a table indexed by the value of the variable x. See the difference:

```
for k = 1,10,1 do
project["models"]["stor"..k]["inputs"]["T_in"]["default"] = 25
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost close.

> *Lua supports this representation by providing a.name as syntactic sugar for a["name"].*
>
> Read more: https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html

You can use only one syntax in time.

Either `tbl.key` or `tbl["key"]`.

The limitation of `.` is that you can only use constant strings in it (which are also [valid variable names](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1)).

In square brackets `[]` you can evaluate runtime expressions.

Correct way to do it:

```lua
project.models["stor"..k].inputs.T_in.default = 25
```

The `.` in `models.["stor"..k]` is unnecessary and causes an error. The correct syntax is just `models["stor"..k]`.

Comment: Wow! I just found this myself too. Thank you very much for the more concise explanation of the syntax! Would `project["models"]["stor"..k]["inputs"]["T_in"]["default"] = 25` work as well?

Comment: @Martin Yes, `project["models"]` is the same as `project.models` for example. (*Exactly* the same)

Comment: @Martin The important part is that you can mix them: `foo.bar["baz"]` or `foo["bar"].baz` both work